# XMLHttpRequest onreadystatechange

Tags: javascript, html

Всем привет.

Появилась проблема при передачи запроса на сервер...

Не понятно почему попадаю в условие `readyState || status` ?

Что происходит в данном коде с `onreadystatechange` ?

Насчёт `Access control allow origin` надо настроить респонс в сервер коде,

Связанно ли както с этим проблема с `onreadystatechange` ?

```js
function registerHandler(user){

   var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

   xhr.onreadystatechange = function(){

    if(xhr.readyState!=4 || xhr.status!=200){
      //Error in Ajax request Why ?

            return alert("Problems with request");
    }
    
    }

        console.log("After onreadystatechange");
        xhr.open("POST","http://localhost:8080/CouponOnWeb/webappl/register",true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type','application/json;charset=utf-8');
        xhr.send(user);  
}

 function registerController(){


    var user = {

    username:document.getElementById("reg_user_name").value,
    firstname:document.getElementById("first_name").value,
    lastname:document.getElementById("last_name").value,
    userid:document.getElementById("user_id").value,
    password:document.getElementById("reg_password").value,
    email:document.getElementById("reg_email").value

    }

   registerHandler(user);

   }
```

```html
<form id = "registrator" onsubmit = "registerController()">
  
  <label for = "reg_user_name">User name:</label>
  <input id = "reg_user_name" name = "reg_user_name" type = "text" placeholder = "user name">
  <br>
  <label for = "first_name">First name:</label>
  <input id = "first_name" name = "first_name" type = "text" placeholder = "first name">
  <br>
  <label for = "last_name">Last name:</label>
  <input id = "last_name" name = "last_name" type = "text" placeholder = "last name">
  <br>
  <label for = "user_id">Id number:</label>
  <input id = "user_id" name = "user_id" type = "number" placeholder = "id number">
  <br>
  <label for = "reg_password">Password:</label>
  <input id = "reg_password" name = "reg_password" type = "password" placeholder = "password">
  <br>
  <label for = "reg_email">Email:</label>
  <input id = "reg_email" name = "reg_email" type = "email" placeholder = "email">
  <br>
  <input id = "reg_button" name = "reg_button" type = "submit" value = "Register">


  </form>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: где в коде _onreadystatechange property_?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24056451/if-xmlhttp-readystate-4-xmlhttp-status-200-in-ajax-not-executing

Comment: *The onreadystatechange event is triggered every time the readyState changes.* - событие вызывается всякий раз, когда изменяется `readyState` (т.е. - многократно) http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp

Comment: Я это читал.. Не понимаю как оно меняется ? 
ready state имеет 4 стадии: 
0: request not initialized 
1: server connection established
2: request received 
3: processing request 
4: request finished and response is ready

Из этого я могу предположить что идёт разговор с сервером ?

Comment: "Igor - тоисть readystate меняется каждый раз при получении определенного ответа от сервера по отношению к запросу ?

Comment: @ zhenyab: По твоей ссылке я нашол такой ответ..
Правельная последовотельность вызова.. 
new XMLHttpRequest
xhr.open()
xhr.onreadystatechange  ...
xhr.send() 

по ссылке на http://www.w3schools.com/ajax/ajax_xmlhttprequest_onreadystatechange.asp, нечего неговорится про такую последовательность в примере и пишется подругому..
Что я должен был найти с твоей ссылке ?

Comment: @Maks.Burkov - нет, readystate меняется при прохождении объектом `xhr` разных стадий в процессе посылания запроса и получания ответа.

Comment: @Igor ок спасибо

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Так?

```
function registerHandler(user){
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
        if (xhr.readyState == 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200) {
                // всё норм
            } else {    
                    alert("Problems with request");
            }    
        }    
    });    
    xhr.open('POST','http://localhost:8080/CouponOnWeb/webappl/register',true);
    xhr.send(user);  
}
```

и на сервере на всякий случай:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: Насчёт сервера не понял..

Comment: В консоли ошибка "...no access-control-allow-origin header...".
Нужно добавить заголовок разрешающий запросы с другого домена.
https://learn.javascript.ru/xhr-crossdomain

Comment: Знаком с этим спс